# SQL: Convert type varchar to type money to be divided. **Divide by zero error encountered**

Tags: sql, sql-server

Error received:

> Divide by zero error encountered

I need to convert type `varchar` in SQL Server to be able to divide by type `money`. I have searched the forums a bunch and can't seem to find an answer that works. Below is what I have currently. When all is done I need to display the answer as a percentage in a report. Thanks to anyone who can help!

```
  cast((CONVERT(DECIMAL, ((OEJUD.Text7/OEJUD.Money1) * 100)))AS varchar(20)) + '%' AS '% Prog Billed'
```

Comment: convert denominator in float. `cast(column as float)`.

Comment: Sorry I wrote the statement backwards.  It should read  cast((CONVERT(DECIMAL, ((OEJUD.Text7/OEJUD.Money1) * 100)))AS varchar(20)) + '%' AS '% Prog Billed',

Comment: @PrabhatG, float is an inexact data type and should under no circumstances ever be used in math calculation or you will have rounding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
select  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),((cast(OEJUD.Text7 as float)/NULLIF(cast(OEJUD.Money1 as float),0))*100))
```

check this sql and after that try

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),((cast(OEJUD.Text7 as float)/NULLIF(cast(OEJUD.Money1 as float),0))*100)) + '%' AS '% Prog Billed'
```

Comment: It gives the same error.  Divide by zero error encountered. Appreciate the help though.

Comment: @snapper0042 updated answer. Try them. Added `NULLIF`

Comment: Same error.  This one has me stumped.  Thanks again for the help though.

Comment: I  just now added NULLIF. Kindly re try :)

Comment: ^^ Apologies you had to re-try several times. Mark it as answer if it helped

Comment: While the null if solves the divide by zero error... one should never cast money as a float due to the imprecise nature of float. better off doing a decimal(16,2) or adjust to size precision needed.

Answer (score 1):

While the NullIf code works, you may need to return something other than null depending on your business requirements, in that case you need a case statement

```
case when OEJUD.Money1 is null or OEJUD.Money1= 0 or isnumeric(EJUD.Text7) = 0 
then '0'
else   
cast(
            (cast(OEJUD.Text7 as money)/EJUD.Money1) * 100

    AS varchar(20)) + ' %' 
End AS '% Prog Billed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type.varchar column is set to 0, some value divided by 0 does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @myMoney Money
DECLARE @myAmount varChar(30)

SET @myMoney = 3
SET @myAmount = '10'

Select cast((CONVERT(DECIMAL, ((@myAmount/NULLIF(@myMoney,0)) * 100)))AS varchar(20))

Comment: Please add an explanation to what was the problem and how you solved it. And format code by indenting 4 spaces or using Ctrl + K

Comment: Indentation fixed, and the problem was with number divided by 0 gives error "Divide by zero error encountered". If we replace 0 with null using IFNULL function, system does not gives error.